# Identifying inherited css classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the below code:

```
<style>
.foo{
color:red;
}
</style>

<div class="foo">
<span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

I have the below jquery code to check if the span tag has the class foo.

```
$("span").hasClass("foo")
```

This returns false. But I want it to return true. How can I check for inherited css classes in jquery?

Comment: You are expecting to check parent's class?

Comment: No immediate parent. The class must be used on the span tag, either on itself directly or on one of its parent

Comment: Please mention these details in question itself. It causing some misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.closest('.foo')`. `.closest()` search for selector on parents and on current element (so span and it's parents)

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('.foo').length > 0)
})
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}

.bar {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="foo">Hello</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="bar">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `.closest()` with a selector

```
$('span').closest('.foo').length > 0
```

```js
console.info('span has foo?', 
  $('span').closest('.foo').length > 0)

console.info('span has bar?', 
  $('span').closest('.bar').length > 0)
  
console.info('span has baz?', 
  $('span').closest('.baz').length > 0)
  
console.info('span has whatever?', 
  $('span').closest('.whatever').length > 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main class="baz">
  <div class="foo">
    <span class="bar">Hello</span>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("span").closest('div')`:

```js
if($("span").closest('div').hasClass("foo")){
  console.log('found');
}
```

```css
.foo{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
<span>Hello</span>
</div>
```